# Symfony and Auth0 - how to get details of logged in user outside of the firewall?

Tags: php, symfony, auth0

I have a Symfony 6 application. I am using [Auth0's Symfony library](https://github.com/auth0/symfony).  I have secured the page `/private` in the firewall. When a user visits `/private` they are *successfully* taken through the login flow and I can use `$this->getUser()` to see their details.

I *also* want to see their details on pages which aren't protected by the firewall. For example, on `/home` I'd like to say "Hello Username" if they're logged in or "Hello anonymous" if they are not.

Is there any way to get the Auth0 user on a page which isn't protected with the firewall?

I tried adding `PUBLIC_ACCESS` to the firewall to allow anyone to access the page even if they weren't logged in:

```yaml
firewalls:
        home:
            pattern: ^/home$ 
            context: user
            stateless: false
            provider: auth0_provider
            custom_authenticators:
                - auth0.authenticator
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: users_in_memory
access_control:
        - { path: ^/home$, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
```

But that still forced unauthenticated users through the login flow.

Is there any way to get a signed-in user's Auth0 details if the page isn't in the firewall?